# Is AFP of any value to non-ancient devices?

Tags: smb, file-sharing, afp

From [one person’s tests](https://photographylife.com/afp-vs-nfs-vs-smb-performance), SMBv3 is just a hair faster than AFP.

All of the Macs, iPads, and iPhones in our house capable of reading disks are Apple devices that support SMBv3.  We have no devices capable of AFP.

File sharing allows SMB **or** “SMB and AFP.”  Is there any benefit to enabling AFP?

I am more accustomed to NFS, but speed of disk access is worth switching over.

Comment: Well, nit-pick: we do have a TV DVR with a disk in it, but we have no intention of sharing other disks with it.  :-)

Answer (score -1):

I personally use SFTP on my home network rather than SMB or NFS, as that allows you to access POSIX file permissions, whereas the others do not. This is a feature offered by AFP, too.

macOS requires POSIX file permissions on users' home directories, so if you plan on having those accessed via the network, SMB is not an option.

Having said that, Apple appears to be phasing out AFP, with no support for APFS volumes (at least not yet). I'd personally stick to just using SMB unless your needs dictate otherwise, in which case, SFTP may be a better choice than AFP simply for its cross-platform support and not being proprietary (though Netatalk provides an AFP solution for Linux).

Comment: SFTP to me is SSH-encrypted FTP.  At least one of the disks needs to be writable by Time Machine.  And one needs iTunes to read/write.  Maybe I should revert to NFS.  Home directories will continue to be local, as the iMac is old enough that some things on it will be incompatible with apps on Catalina.

Comment: *"SFTP to me is SSH-encrypted FTP."* — SFTP and FTP are completely different protocols. Not only are FTP and FTPS notoriously insecure, but SFTP offers filesystem-like operations such as listing directory contents; it's *designed* to be used for this purpose, unlike FTP. —— If you want to use SFTP, you can use [`osxfuse`](https://osxfuse.github.io/) to mount network directories, which will suffice for iTunes etc. —— If you don't want to go with SFTP, then NFS is a decent choice; I'd certainly prefer it over SMB/CIFS where reasonable (access speeds not an issue, in a non-Microsoft environment)

Comment: Would also prefer it to be Finder-browsable, though that's not as important.  Will look into osxfuse, though if I can do things completely native, it's nicer.